# Estimating number of recursive calls in binomial function (Sedgewick Algorithms, 4th Edition)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Part of exercise 1.1.27 of "Algorithms, 4th Edition" by Robert Sedgewick is to estimate the number of recursive calls made by this function:

```
public static double binomial(int n, int k, double p) {
    if((n == 0) && (k == 0)) return 1;
    if((n < 0) || (k < 0)) return 0;
    return (1 - p) * binomial(n - 1, k, p) + p * binomial(n - 1, k - 1, p);
}
```

When it is called as follows: `binomial(100, 50, 0.25)`.

Unfortunately, I have no idea what my thought process should be when solving this type of problem. I thought about running the method with lesser values in hopes of finding a pattern, but I have no idea how I could relate this given that there are 3 different variables, two of which influence the recursive base case.

If anyone could provide insight on how to solve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with doing what the computer does when a function is called - evaluate it. Try to put in the "100, 50, 0.25" in the parameters and see what the next recursive call will be. Then try to execute the next iteration as well. Go for some 10-20 iterations deep, and you'll start getting a sense of how long it will take.

Comment: Note that the number of recursive call does not depend on p.

Comment: Solve it for `k = 0`.  Then solve it for `k = 1`.  Then `k = 2`.  Keep going until you see a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just some tips, hope to help you:

1. The end point of recursion is `p * binomial(N - 1, k - 1, p)`.
2. When the computation encounter the first one end point, it has `N` layers for loop wrapped.
3. Combined 1 & 2, we can infer that `T(N) = N * T(N - 1)`.

So the estimation of 1.1.27 is `N!`, AKA `100!`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really having hard time to understand the pattern you can calculate by changing a bit the code itself to give you the number of recursion pretty easily:

```
double binomial(int n, int k, double p) {
    if ((n == 0) && (k == 0)) 
        return 0;

    if ((n < 0) || (k < 0)) 
        return 0;

    return binomial(n - 1, k, p) + binomial(n - 1, k - 1, p) + 2;
}
```

And another tip, try to find the actual end point of the recursion and what does it mean for k and n (notice that k isn't always get to 0 and try to understand when and what is the pattern)